# How to disable enum value in UI from domain layer

Tags: c#, enums, domain-driven-design

I have an application where domain and user interface are separate layers. Both have access to some enums that are defined in the infrastructure layer. Different teams work on the different layers.

Some values of an enum do not have fully implemented code yet in the domain or may be disabled in a trial version of the app. What I would like to do is show those values in a dropdown menu in the UI, but disable them until the domain code is fully implemented. At which time there is no need for any additional work in the UI layer so the domain team can simply enable it.

What is the best way to achieve this?

- is there an attribute I can set on an enum value?
- do I need to specify it on a DTO or on the mapper to a DTO?
- something else?

Not worried about how to do the UI portion, only about how to pass the information to the UI. Not asking about an implementation per se, but rather a concept. For what it is worth, backend is C#, frontend is HTML5, MVVM using MVC.NET, WCF, Unity.

Comment: If your Domain knows about infrastructure, then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: it only knows about common structs and enums. Just like it knows about List, arrays, dictionaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have it figured out and it was actually very simple.

You can indeed add attributes to individual enum values (as opposed to the enum itself which is more commonplace) and these do not need to be custom, although they could.

MSDN has the complete list of available attributes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.ComponentModel(v=vs.110).aspx).

I ended up using this one:
`[EditorBrowsableAttribute(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]`

Where `EditorBrowsableState.Never` is used for those enum values that are not yet implemented and changed to `EditorBrowsableState.Always` when they are.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom attribute for your enum and filter on the attribute based on environment. I am not sure of this is good or bad practice though.